# Unable to link Adsense to Market account on Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

I'm an android developer with few free apps published on android's market.
I've recently opened a new GoogleCheckout & adsense accounts, in order to receive payments.

All the accounts are valid, working and can be accessed.
All the account opened under the same gmail account, and same details.

But when i'm trying to LINK my Adsense account to my merchant account on Developer Console screen, i keep getting this error:

" **Failed to add the provided AdSense account. Please check your AdSense Publisher ID and try again. If you received an error message previously, please refresh this page before re-submitting your AdSense Publisher ID.** "

I've searched over the web, and i could see that many people had this problem, but couldn't find a solution.
Did anyone find a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had a bug, and notified everyone that it has been solved.